# Basic template question: Combine several products on one page?

Tags: magento-1.8, template, product-list

I am currently trying to decide whether Magento would be a good system for our new (planned) webshop. What I am looking for is better insight into how I can influence the display of products.

My understanding is that Magento uses templates which basically combine php and html. I know about grid and list views when selecting categories of products. I am not familiar with the details of the templating language, e.g. includes, hierarchical of building blocks structures etc.

What I would like to know is if (and how) I can for example display two or more products side by side on one page. My database query will result in very few selected products and I would like to show them all (in more detail than grid/list view provides) on one page, maybe with a comparision table etc.

So basically my question is, if I can throw a list of products (an array?) to a template, and the template uses standardized building blocks (includes?) for each product?

Comment: You could simply expand the grid or list view templates to show all the info you require. Compare Products comes as standard in grid & list views

Answer (score 0):

You can have a product list block which uses a list template and renders whatever query you define inside the block.